# The XMLHttpRequest compatibility library was not found

Tags: angular, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular-material

I am doing a project with Angular and Firebase and I started to get this error. At first I didnt have this error, but then I used FirebaseTSAuth methods and the error appeared. Can someone help?
This is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUivF.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).